# Remote Desktop via chrome using C#.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-chrome

Is there any way I can use chrome remote desktop api to take remote desktop of remote machine (Not within organisation) from my windows application. Please guide me the steps to achieve this.

Comment: since 4 years ago the topic is closed. But now c# has already the cool cefsharp which is chromeembed engine that can be used as @Parth asked for....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't have a Remote Desktop API, Chrome has a Remote Desktop browser extension (just to clarify). There's no way to open an instance of the Chrome web browser (to run the Remote Desktop extension) from within a Windows application.

If your application needs a remote desktop style functionality, you could look at downloading and modifying an open source project like VNC. Make sure you read VNC's license agreement to make sure you're following their legal terms and conditions. 
https://www.realvnc.com/products/open/

**Wikipedia VNC page:**

"In computing, Virtual Network Computing (VNC) is a graphical desktop sharing system that uses the Remote Frame Buffer protocol (RFB) to remotely control another computer. It transmits the keyboard and mouse events from one computer to another, relaying the graphical screen updates back in the other direction, over a network.[1]"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing

Hope this helps with your project!

Comment: Thanks but it will work outside the organisation or not ? For example my clients PC in somewhere else and I want to access that using some unique identifier like Public IP or mac address

Comment: The software supports connecting to computers outside your local network (to anywhere in the world), but whether it will work between yourself and your client's PC will depend on your firewall settings. VNC uses ports 5900-5901 by default, so these would need to be open on both your firewall and theirs for a connection to work.

Comment: Actually nowadays Chrome has such API. And application can launch Chrome by means of selenium driver or other such tools.